# Crash during clicking on a button second time

Tags: reactjs

When I click add  patient first, its works properly but again I clicked on the add patient button the page go to crash. What will I do?

```
 render() {
        const { patientsMasterData, addPatientForm, onGetTimelyFiling, PatientInfo,addRelatedClaim } = this.props;
    return (
                <ul className="add-list add-patient-menu">

                    <li>
                        <div className="add-list_key">
                            Referred By<span className="add-list_required"> *</span>
                        </div>
                        {/* <div className="add-list_value">
                            <Field
                                name="ReferredBy"
                                component="select"
                                onChange={this.onChange}>
                                <option value="0">Select</option>
                                {patientsMasterData.ReferredBy && patientsMasterData.ReferredBy.map(referredObj =>
                                    <option key={referredObj.RefID} value={referredObj.RefID}>{referredObj.RefName}</option>
                                )}
                            </Field> */}

                        <div className="add-list_value1">
                        <ReactAutocomplete
                                    name="ReferredBy"
                                    items = {patientsMasterData && patientsMasterData.ReferredBy && patientsMasterData.ReferredBy.map(referredObj =>(
                                        {options:referredObj.RefName,
                                        values:referredObj.RefID}
                                        ))
                                    }
                                    shouldItemRender={(item, value) => item.options.toLowerCase().indexOf(value.toLowerCase()) > -1}
                                    getItemValue={(item) => item.options}
                                    renderItem={(item, highlighted) =>
                                        <div
                                        key={item.values}
                                        style={{ backgroundColor: highlighted ? '#3db4e5' : '#FFFFFF',cursor:'pointer', border:'1px solid lighten($grey-element,30%)',padding: '5px' }} >
                                        {item.options}
                                        </div>}
                                    inputProps={{placeholder:'Select...'}}
                                    menuStyle={this.props.menuStyle}
                                    wrapperStyle={this.props.wrapperStyle}
                                    value={this.state.value}
                                    onChange={this.onValueChange}
                                    onSelect={this.onValueChange}
                        />
                        </div>
                    </li>            
                    {addPatientForm && addPatientForm.values.ReferredBy && addPatientForm.values.ReferredBy!==0 &&
                        this.state.isSubref &&
                    <li>
                        <div className="add-list_key">
                           SubRef By<span className="add-list_required"> * 
                        </span> </div>
                        <div className="add-list_value">
                                <Field name="SubRefID" component="select" >
                                        <option value='0'>Select</option>
                                        {patientsMasterData.SubRef && patientsMasterData.SubRef.map(referredObj =>
                                            <option key={referredObj.SubRefID} value={referredObj.SubRefID}>{referredObj.Name}</option>
                                        )}
                                </Field>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    }
```

This is my code,What change need to make in my code inorder to avoid the crash.On crash time the console shows an error, referred by is undefined in `addPatientForm && addPatientForm.values.ReferredBy && addPatientForm.values.ReferredBy!==0 && this.state.isSubref` this condition.

Comment: Can you create stackblitz link for reproduce your problem?

Comment: I don't know how to create it

Answer (score 0):

Add check for `addPatientForm.values` as well and let me know if it still crashes.

Comment: I added that condition in {addPatientForm.values? addPatientForm && addPatientForm.values.ReferredBy && addPatientForm.values.ReferredBy!==0 && this.state.isSubref .... :' ' But it doesn't works

Comment: By the code you have provided it looks like you have not. 
``addPatientForm && addPatientForm.values.ReferredBy``

Comment: It checks if you have addPatientForm, then tries to access values and ReferredBy inside those values. If there is no values then it would crash.